# Spring integration throttling

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Does anyone know if there is already a component to handle throttling in the spring integration framework?

Essentially, what I am looking for is something similar to this:

```
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

class Throttler extends TimerTask{
  final RateLimiter rateLimiter;
  Timer timer;
  Long rate;
  Long dailyLimit;
  Long dailyCount;
  Long hourlyLimit;
  Long hourlyCount;
  Long resetTime;

  public Throtteler(){
    rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(rate);
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(this, 60000);
  }

  public void run() {
    synchronize(this){
        hourlyCount = 0;
        resetTime = System.currentTimeMiilis();
        //if midnight reset daily counter
    }
  }

  public boolean throttled(Object obj){
    rateLimiter.acquire();
    if(hourlyCount < hourlyLimit && dailyCount < dailyLimit){
        hourlyCount++;
    }else{
        audit();
        // evaluate rules for throttled message
        // queue for hourly throttle?
        // return error for daily throttle?
    }
  }
}
```

Where the rate limiter will limit the per second transactions and the daily and hourly transactions are tracked by this object and this object is held in a persistent cache for each tenant using my service.

Comment: Google search: https://github.com/williewheeler/kite

Comment: Almost, but no.  I am not looking for concurrency throttling, which is what I found with every google search I did. concurrency is not the same as multi-tenancy and multi-tenancy is what I a want. Additionally the rate limiter does do hourly rates which is useful but it is limited to just that, hourly. Finally, its not part of the spring integration code base. I am looking for a "Spring Integration" implementation of a throttler, if there is not one in spring integration then I will write my own.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure what you mean, so would be good if you raise a JIRA issue (https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) on the matter and share more info there. Eventually you would be able to contribute the final solution to the framework. Thanks!